Why is my headset microphone on Mac Mini 2012 not working? Does Pipewire have something to do with it?
I have a Mac Mini from 2012 and I finally made the switch to Ubuntu 24.04.1 the day before yesterday. Everything went fine and seemed to be great until I realized that my microphone isn't showing up. This mac mini computer has an audio port that accepts typical earphones (TRRS jack) which matches my headset and which apparently doubles as an SPDIF connector. It also has a line-in port but I don't use that. Before the switch to Ubuntu, the microphone worked perfectly. I suspect there's some kind of a switch or sensor inside because my old Mac system knew when the earphone/microphone was plugged in. Now, audio is coming out fine but I can't get the microphone to work. I can't help but wonder if Pipewire is not configured correctly to detect when the microphone is plugged in. I have tried searching for answers about this on forums but nothing seems to help.
